# There are some issues with using makefile to generate iso files

Tags: c++, c, assembly, makefile, operating-system

i need to execute

`make all`

but  there will be errors

`make: *** No rule to make target 'build/iso', needed by 'build/menghanOS.ios'.  Stop.`

I'm confused

When I checked the makefile file, I found that

```
BUILD_DIR := build
BIN_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/bin
ISO_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/iso
ISO_BOOT_DIR := $(IOS_DIR)/boot
IOS_GRUB_DIR := $(ISO_BOOT_DIR)/grub

OS_NAME = menghanOS
OS_BIN = $(OS_NAME).bin
OS_ISO = $(OS_NAME).ios
$(BUILD_DIR)/$(OS_ISO):  $(ISO_DIR) $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_BIN) GRUB_TEMPLATE
    @./config-grub.sh ${OS_NAME} > $(ISO_GRUB_DIR)/grub.cfg
    @cp $(BIN_DIR)/$(OS_BIN) $(ISO_BOOT_DIR)
    @grub-mkrescue -o $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OS_ISO) $(ISO_DIR)

all: clean $(BUILD_DIR)/$(OS_ISO)
clean:
    @rm -rf $(BUILD_DIR)
```

Maybe there's a problem here

the GRUB_TEMPLATE:

```
timeout=0

menuentry "$_OS_NAME" {
    multiboot /boot/$_OS_NAME.bin
}
```

the config-grub.sh:

```
export _OS_NAME=$1

cat GRUB_TEMPLATE | envsubst > "$2"
```

In addition, the permissions for the makefile file are as follows:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 1934 Jul 16 16:20 makefile*
```

I need to know why such an error occurred

Comment: Perhaps start by fixing the places where ISO is spelled IOS

Comment: Side note: Don't use `all: clean other_targets ...`. Rules for prerequisites may run in parallel and order of execution is undefined.

Comment: I am foolish,It's my spelling problem

Comment: This issue has nothing to do with iso files in particular.

Answer (score 0):

The error message concerns two targets, `build/iso` and `build/menghanOS.ios`.  The latter corresponds to `$(BUILD_DIR)/$(OS_ISO)`, the target of the first rule.  The former corresponds to `$(ISO_DIR)`, one of the prerequisites of the first rule.

`make` has apparently been asked to build `build/menghanOS.ios`, perhaps by virtue of that being the default target.  To do so, it must ensure that all that target's prerequisites are up to date. The error message indicates that `build/iso` does not already exist, in which case `make` expects to have a rule for that target (presumably to create it), but there is no such rule in the makefile.  `make` then terminates with an error because the prerequisites of `build/menghanOS.ios` cannot be satisfied.

The makefile seems to assume that there will be a rule for building `build/iso`, presumably something like:

```
$(ISO_DIR):
        mkdir -p $@
```

Adding that or an equivalent should resolve this particular issue.

---

Side note: it is poor form and probably counterproductive for your `all` target to include `clean` as a prerequisite.  And it is unconventional to provide an `all` target that is not also the default target.  Most people familiar with `make` will expect `make all` to have the same effect as bare `make`, at least if the former has any useful effect at all, but those will have different effects with your makefile.  And as it stands, your makefile is unlikely to work reliably with parallel `make`.  If you want to provide a target for a clean build then name it something else, and structure it to ensure that all the cleaning is done prior to any building.  Or on the other hand, how hard is it, really, to type `make clean; make all`?